# How can I make this deploy/init run as a non root user?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I have init script which should run as non root user. How can I make it? Ubuntu 12.04

```
#!/bin/sh 
DEPLOY_BIN=/usr/share/deploy/bin
PID_FILE=/var/run/deploy.pid 
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$DEPLOY_BIN DAEMON=$DEPLOY_BIN/reporting
NAME=deploy 
DESC="Deploy" if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "You need root privileges to run this script"
        exit 1 fi . /lib/lsb/init-functions if [ -r /etc/default/rcS ]; then
        . /etc/default/rcS fi case "$1" in
  start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC"
        pid=`pidofproc -p $PID_FILE deploy`
        if [ -n "$pid" ] ; then
                log_begin_msg "Already running."
                log_end_msg 0
                exit 0
        fi
        # Start Daemon
        start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile "$PID_FILE" --make-pidfile --background --exec $DAEMON
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC"
        if [ -f "$PID_FILE" ]; then
                start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile "$PID_FILE" \
                        --retry=TERM/20/KILL/5 >/dev/null
                if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
                        log_progress_msg "$DESC is not running but pid file exists, cleaning up"
                elif [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
                        PID="`cat $PID_FILE`"
                        log_failure_msg "Failed to stop $DESC (pid $PID)"
                        exit 1
                fi
                rm -f "$PID_FILE"
        else
                log_progress_msg "(not running)"
        fi
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc -p $PID_FILE  deploy && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        if [ -f "$PID_FILE" ]; then
                $0 stop
                sleep 1
        fi
        $0 start
        ;;
  *)
        log_success_msg "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}"
        exit 1
        ;; esac exit 0
```

Comment: that's what sudo is for.  configure sudo to allow that user to run that script as root.

Comment: Is the only way?

Comment: I can not understand  if you want that a non-root user can run the script or if you want that  the process launched by the script will be run under different user than root.

Comment: I want that a non-root user can run the script. @LilloX

Comment: so as @cas writed the only solution is to use sudo because as you can see to run the script is needed root level.

Comment: @LilloX yes but it's not possible to modify the above  script and run it as non root ?Are you sure

Comment: Also asked at Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/694251/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1: `sudo` rules

Add to your `sudoers` file (using `visudo`) the following rule:

```
<user_name> ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:<path/to/your/script>
```

Replacing `<user_name>` to your non-root user login name and `<path/to/your/script>` with the **absolute** path to what you want to execute.

The same operation may be done by placing that rule inside a file under `/etc/sudoers.d`. Note that such file must be owned by `root:root` and have the mode 0440 in order to work with `sudo`.

The `NOPASSWD` flag is optional here, depending on whether you want your user to provide the password to authenticate the action or not. That is purely up to your decisions about who can do what and how easy.

After that it's done, you may execute it with `sudo <script>` from your non-root user.

NOTE: Check your user's `sudo` rules with `sudo -l`

### Solution 2: (PITA) Check all ownerships and permissions

In order to allow a non-root user to run as itself the script, be sure that everything done by the script and the daemon that starts within is inside the allowed actions of the executing user. That means:

- The user must have proper permissions to any device used by the daemon
- The user must have proper permissions to read/write/execute any folder inside a path that tries to access
- The user must have proper permissions to read/write any file that needs to be opened.

So yes, it is possible, but I would definitely go for the `sudo` rule

**EDIT**: Of course, you will need to delete the line in the script where the UID is compared with 0 (root) done here

```
[...]
if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
[...]
```

Comment: If possible can you give me an example for the solution 2

Comment: For example, you want to create the PID file in `/var/run/deploy.pid`, you will need to ensure that your user can execute and write in the folder `/var/run/`, so that the file `deploy.pid` may be created. Check the permissions and ownership with `ls -l /var/run` and decide if you want to change them with `chown` or `chmod`. But as I said: **absolutely not** recommended. System paths and devices should be left as they came when you installed the system, unless you know very well what you are doing and why.

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't want to change the user permission or ownership at /var/run. Without that how can i make it ?

Comment: if you cannot (or do not want to) change permissions or ownerships, then you can only go ahead with a `sudo` rule, or not doing this at all.

Comment: If suppose if i keep the pid file to somewhere else rather than /var/run then also it's not possible?

Comment: @dave_alcarin another alternative would be to change the location the PID file would be placed to avoid changing /var/run/. It's not uncommon for PID files to be placed in a similar directory as it's parent application (for example mysql places it's PID file in [mysql root]/tmp/, you could place the PID file in `dirname $0` to place it in the same directory as the script.

Comment: @Dave yes sure, you can change the location of your PID file, but that's only the tip of the iceberg. The main problem is that you have to ensure that your script, daemon, process, etc. can run properly, i.e. no permission/access errors throughout execution, without being root.

Comment: @dave_alcarin I agree that the PID is the tip of the iceberg, but the OP has an interest in running it as non-root, and exploring the permissions throughout execution is really the only way to answer that. I only mentioned the PID file because it was a specific example